# How to disable sequence in activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter without rails?

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

I am only using ActiveRecord to some development with a legacy Oracle database. My adapter is activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced). So I don't want to AR  handle the primary key generation. How to disable the primary key generated by a sequence?

```
class User < Activied::Base
  self.table_name = "users"
  self.primary_key = "user_id"
end

user = User.new
user.save
```

Then I got the error:

```
stmt.c:230:in oci8lib_191.so: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist (OCIError)
```

When I change my code to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'users'
  self.primary_key = "user_id"
  self.sequence_name = nil
end
```

I got another error:

```
stmt.c:230:in oci8lib_191.so: ORA-00936: missing expression (OCIError)
```

So is there anyone know how to manage the primary key manually? I just want to do some simple insert.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late but finaly I found answer. Shortly:

```
self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
```

From the source code comment [here](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb):

> ## Usage notes:
>
> ```
> # * Key generation assumes a "${table_name}_seq" sequence is available
> # for all tables; the sequence name can be changed using
> # ActiveRecord::Base.set_sequence_name. When using Migrations, these
> # sequences are created automatically.
>
> # ***Use set_sequence_name :autogenerated **** with legacy tables that have
> # triggers that populate primary keys automatically.**
> ```